# How can I fetch information about a specific repository in github owned by an Organization?

Tags: git, api, github, github-api

I'm using the github API to fetch information programmatically about different repositories and I'm running into an issue.

I know I have access to the private repos with my auth key because I was able to programmatically create a repo.

Here's the PHP curl code I'm using:

```
$url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/<VALID ORG>/repos';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: token <myvalidauthtoken>';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$r = json_decode($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Right now this code successfully pulls all the repos from my organization, but we have 500+ repositories, so it's not feasible to pull them ALL down just for information about one repos information. (From http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories)

Now, if I look at user owned repositories (not organization repositories), I find that the request should look like this:

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo` (http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)

and right now my format is:

`GET /orgs/:org/repos` (http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories)

so I tried a couple of permutations on URL:

```
$url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/<VALID ORG>/repos/<VALIDREPO>';
$url = 'https://api.github.com/<VALID ORG>/<VALIDREPO>';
$url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/<VALID ORG>/repos/<VALIDREPO>';
$url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/orgs/<VALID ORG>/repos/VALIDREPO>';
```

But ALL of these failed. Any ideas fellow geeks?

Comment: define "failed". **what error/response exactly are you getting?**

Comment: 404 responses from the header, so obviously none of these are valid URLs to the repos.

Comment: no, that's not necessarily the case. 404s are also returned if you do not have permission to view the requested item, and in some other situations

Comment: I've definitely verified that my authentication key is valid for these repositories. I created one of the repositories that I'm trying to source using the same auth key.

Comment: Also, the original code I posted lists ALL the private repositories I have. Like I said, I don't want to pull down the data from 500 repositories and have to parse everything, it would be nice to just pull down the one repository.

Comment: The url format `https://api.github.com/repos/<VALID ORG>/<VALIDREPO>` as given by [repos#get](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) (and quoted by you) works fine for me. example: https://api.github.com/repos/S25RTTR-Aux/s25rttr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I did this.

For the record, Nevik was right in the format for organizations:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<VALID ORG>/<VALIDREPO>
```

I set my URL like so:

```
$url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/$org_name/$repo_name';
```

See the problem yet?

In PHP, the single quote does not parse internal variables, the double quote does:

```
$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/$org_name/$repo_name";
```

And everything was fixed.

Thanks again for the sanity check Nevik!